# How to find value closest to List of values?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write an algorithm that returns the closest value within a list of values. So in a List(4.0, 6.0, 2.0) the closest value to 7.0 is 6.0

Below is the code I'm using but it's not correct as the closest value being returned is 4 :

How can fix below code or is there a Scala utility method I can use to solve this ?

```
    val num = 7.0                             //> num  : Double = 7.0
    val listNums = List[Double](4,6,2)        //> listNums  : List[Double] = List(4.0, 6.0, 2.0)


    def getClosest(num : Double , listNums : List[Double]) = {

      var min = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE
    var closest = num

    for(x <- listNums ){

    val diff = x - num
   if(num < min){
    min = diff
    closest = x
    }
   }

   closest

    }                                         //> getClosest: (num: Double, listNums: List[Double])Double

val closest = getClosest(num , listNums)  //> closest  : Double = 4.0
```

Comment: Just a query regarding this. What if the list is like this listNums = List[Double](4,6,2,8). Now both 6 and 8 are closest!

Comment: @Anuj Mehta I would just expect the first one matched to be returned

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is almost a one-liner with `minBy`:

```
def getClosest(num: Double, listNums: List[Double]) =
  listNums.minBy(v => math.abs(v - num))
```

`minBy` is unfortunately a *partial* function—it'll crash with an exception when called on an empty list. To match the behavior of your implementation, you can write the following:

```
def getClosest(num: Double, listNums: List[Double]) = listNums match {
  case Nil => Double.MaxValue
  case list => list.minBy(v => math.abs(v - num))
}
```

The problem with your code is that you're not taking the absolute value, as the other answer implicitly points out. Don't use `Math.abs`, though—that's shorthand for `java.lang.Math.abs`. `math.abs` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation would be:

```
def getClosest(num : Double , list : List[Double]) :Double = list match {
    case x :: xs => list.foldLeft(x){(ans,next) => 
                     if(math.abs(next - num) < math.abs(ans - num)) next else ans }
    case Nil => throw new RuntimeException("Empty list")
  }

scala> getClosest(20, List(1,19,22,24))
res0: Double = 19.0
```

A more general implementation would be:

```
  def getClosest[A: Numeric](num: A, list: List[A]): A = {
    val im = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
    list match {
      case x :: xs => list.minBy (y => im.abs(im.minus(y, num)))
      case Nil => throw new RuntimeException("Empty list")
    }
  }
```

Thanks to @Travis for suggesting `minBy`. It is much more prettier than `foldLeft`

Comment: There's really no need to write a manual fold here given the existence of `minBy`, and `math.abs` should be preferred to `Math.abs`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yes agreed :). Hence I upvoted your answer!

Comment: One other note—you could use the standard operators in your generic version by importing `Numeric.Implicits._` and `Ordering.Implicits._` if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Define an [Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) by distance from your selected number, and use the `min` mathod from [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) applying this ordering.

I don't have a scala install handy right now to provide a coded tested solution, but the two pieces of this are relatively easy.

Comment: Defining this kind of `Ordering` instance for `Double` isn't really as clean or idiomatic as using `minBy`, which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be more generic, you can try this:

```
def getClosest[A: Numeric](value: A, elems: Traversable[A]): A = {
  val ops = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
  elems.minBy(e => ops.abs(ops.minus(e, value)))
}
```

Then:

```
getClosest(20, List(1, 19, 22, 24))         
    //> res1: Int = 19
getClosest(BigDecimal("5000000000000000"), List(BigDecimal(1), BigDecimal(19)))
    //> res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 19
```